# Python performance using Boost Python doesn't improve

Tags: python, c++, performance, boost, numpy

I'm working on a big computer vision project and I need to do some processing on every frame coming from multiple cameras. It's quite heavy and I would like to improve the speed. So I thought of wrapping a python function in c++ using boost python.

Here the function I want to wrap in c++:

```
def computeSumInboundingbox(self, cameraTable, integral):   
   for line in cameraTable:
        minX, minY, maxX, maxY = line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5]
        # sum of the pixel in the bounding box according to integral image
        sumBox = integral[(minY,minX)] + integral[(maxY, maxX)] - integral[(maxY,minX)] - integral[(minY,maxX)]
        # we scale the sumBox
        if sumBox != 0: 
            self.bitmap[line[0],line[1]] = \
                float(sumBox) / ((maxX - minX) * (maxY - minY))
```

This function is reading some coordinates from a the 2D list ***cameraTable*** ( a look up table). This table has been loaded during the initialisation of my class. ***Integral*** and ***bitmap*** are 2d numpy array.
I have a lot of coordinates so doing this every frame is a bit slow.

Then I wrap the function in c++.

```
boost::python::numeric::array computeSumInboundingbox(boost::python::numeric::array integral, list cameraTable, boost::python::numeric::array bitmap)
{
 list currCameraTable;
 float sumBox;
 for (int i = 0 ; i < len(cameraTable) ; i++)
 {   
    int x = extract<float>(cameraTable[i][0]);
    int y = extract<float>(cameraTable[i][1]);
    float minX = extract<float>(cameraTable[i][2]);
    float minY = extract<float>(cameraTable[i][3]);
    float maxX = extract<float>(cameraTable[i][4]);
    float maxY = extract<float>(cameraTable[i][5]);

    // // sum of the pixel in the bounding box according of integral image
    sumBox = extract<float>(integral[make_tuple(minY, minX)] + integral[make_tuple(maxY, maxX)] - 
            integral[make_tuple(maxY, minX)] - integral[make_tuple(minY, maxX)]);
    // we scale the sumBox 
    if (sumBox != 0)
        bitmap[make_tuple(y,x)] = sumBox / ((maxX - minX) * (maxY - minY));
 }

return bitmap;
}
```

But I got a really bad performance and a video of 2000 frames and it took 45 second more to run!

Then I thought the extract function might take a while to process so first I converted my 2D list in a 1D std::vector in python (I didn't really find a way to create a 2D vector)

```
boost::python::numeric::array computeSumInboundingbox(boost::python::numeric::array integral, std::vector<float> cameraTable, boost::python::numeric::array bitmap)
{
 list currCameraTable;
 float sumBox;
 int x;
 int y;
 float minX, minY, maxX, maxY;

 for (int i = 0 ; i < cameraTable.size() ; i+=6)
 {   
    int x = cameraTable[i];
    int y = cameraTable[i+1];
    float minX = cameraTable[i+2];
    float minY = cameraTable[i+3];
    float maxX = cameraTable[i+4];
    float maxY = cameraTable[i+5];

    // // sum of the pixel in the bounding box according of integral image
    sumBox = extract<float>(integral[make_tuple(minY, minX)] + integral[make_tuple(maxY, maxX)] - 
            integral[make_tuple(maxY, minX)] - integral[make_tuple(minY, maxX)]);
    // we scale the sumBox
    if (sumBox != 0)
        bitmap[make_tuple(y,x)] = sumBox / ((maxX - minX) * (maxY - minY));
 }

return bitmap;
}
```

And just for information:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Mapper_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    using namespace std;

    boost::python::numeric::array::set_module_and_type("numpy", "ndarray");

    class_<vector<float> >("VectorFloat")
    .def(vector_indexing_suite<vector<float> > ());

    def("computeSumInboundingbox", computeSumInboundingbox);
}
```

Here are the processing time of the three function for 2000frames

- python function = 100s
- 1st c++ function = 145s
- 2nd c++ function = 121s

Even the 2nd c++ function is better than 1st one, it's still slower than only using python. Why? I thought using C++ would be faster especially with a for loop. Is there anyway I can get c++ performing faster than python or am I wasting my time here?

Here is my numba version. At the beginning my createFloorBitmap method was inside my class and I added the numba decorator to the class, but i couldn't et it work so I moved the method out of the class. setup() and execute() are inherited from the object Node.

```
class Mapper(Node):
 def setup(self):
 # initialise some parameters self.bitmap, self.coordTable
 def execute(self,data):
 # main function
  integral = data['image']
  self.bitmap[:] = 0
  self.bitmap = createFloorBitmap(self.bitmap, self.coordTable, integral)
  return self.bitmap

@jit(f8[:,::1](f8[:,::1], f8[:,::1], f8[:,::1]))       
def createFloorBitmap(bitmap, lines, integral):
 for row in range(lines.shape[0]):
    minX, minY, maxX, maxY = lines[row, 2], lines[row, 3], lines[row, 4], lines[row, 5]
    sumBox = integral[minY,minX] + integral[maxY, maxX] - integral[maxY,minX] - integral[minY,maxX]
    if sumBox != 0:
        bitmap[lines[row, 1],lines[row, 0]] = float(sumBox) / ((maxX - minX) * (maxY - minY))   
return bitmap
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the speed by using array as index, here is the code:

```
w = 600

integral = np.random.randint(0, 255, (w, w))
bitmap = np.zeros_like(integral)

lines = np.random.randint(0, w, (10000, 6))

def computeSumInboundingbox(bitmap, cameraTable, integral):   
   for line in cameraTable:
        minX, minY, maxX, maxY = line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5]
        sumBox = integral[(minY,minX)] + integral[(maxY, maxX)] - integral[(maxY,minX)] - integral[(minY,maxX)]
        if sumBox != 0: 
            bitmap[line[0],line[1]] = float(sumBox) / ((maxX - minX) * (maxY - minY))

def computeSumInboundingbox2(bitmap, line, integral):
    tx, ty, minx, miny, maxx, maxy = line.T
    sumBox = integral[miny, minx] + integral[maxy, maxx] - integral[maxy, minx] - integral[miny, maxx]
    mask = sumBox != 0
    bitmap[tx[mask], ty[mask]] = (sumBox.astype(float)[mask] / ((maxx - minx) * (maxy - miny))[mask])    

bitmap1 = np.zeros_like(integral)
bitmap2 = np.zeros_like(integral)
computeSumInboundingbox(bitmap1, lines, integral)
computeSumInboundingbox2(bitmap2, lines, integral)
print np.allclose(bitmap1, bitmap2)
```

here is the time:

```
computeSumInboundingbox: 10 loops, best of 3: 42.4 ms per loop
computeSumInboundingbox2: 100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop
```

for why c++ is slow, because you use python object level methods to do the array indexing. You can use cython, which know how to access the data in c level.

**EDIT**

Here is a numba version:

```
import numba
@numba.jit("void(i4[:,::1], i4[:,::1], i4[:,::1])")
def computeSumInboundingbox3(bitmap, lines, integral):
    for row in range(lines.shape[0]):
        minX, minY, maxX, maxY = lines[row, 2], lines[row, 3], lines[row, 4], lines[row, 5]
        sumBox = integral[minY,minX] + integral[maxY, maxX] - integral[maxY,minX] - integral[minY,maxX]
        if sumBox != 0:
            bitmap[lines[row, 0],lines[row, 1]] = float(sumBox) / ((maxX - minX) * (maxY - minY))
```

and the speed:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 119 µs per loop
```

Comment: Or, use the Numpy C-API functions to access the data directly from c++.

Comment: Thanks HYRY that's really faster! I'm not enough familiar with numpy to think i could do this.
Do you think I can still improve performance using python?

Comment: If use cython correctly, the performance can be imporved, but I think `computeSumInboundingbox2` is very near to compiled speed, there is no need to make your code complex, if the speed is enough.

Comment: Actually in my case if I could get better speed it would be better, because I'm trying to work with higher resolution for my bitmap image

Comment: I added a numba version, it's about 10x faster than `computeSumInboundingbox2`.

Comment: I tried the numba version in Ipython and it's really faster. but when I tried it inside my project, it's x100 slower than the bumpy array indexing! How is that possible?
The function from another function inside a class for every frame

Comment: @HYRY           I sill can't figure out why numba is slow. It is taking the same time as a normal python function. Such as it had no effect at all. I'm using multiprocessing, could that be the issue? Thanks

Comment: You are using floats as index, I think this makes the calculation slow. Use `@jit(f8[:,::1](f8[:,::1], i4[:,::1], f8[:,::1]))`, and convert self.coordTable to integer array: `self.coordTable = self.coordTable.astype(np.int32)`